# Automation between Google Sheets and BigQuery

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery, automation, data-analysis

I have Google Sheets that update online and every morning a new sheet(tab) is automatically added to it.
I am trying to build a dataset in BigQuery, which pulls the data from the sheets.
I connected the sheets to Bigquery, the problem that I have to manually add the new tab (range) to the table inside the dataset.
Is there a way in which all the sheets that are added to the Sheets will automatically enter to the bigQuery?
Does such a feature exist? Or do i need to build an automation for it?

I connected the sheets to Bigquery.
i'm trying to do it aoutomaticly